# ODE function in R

Tags: r, model, ode, exponential

Relatively new with R and ODE modeling in R. I was wondering if anyone can help me explain in layman terms what the terms within this code mean. I know what the output is, however I cannot simply explain what "with", "as.list", and "list(c(dY))" represent.

```
test = function(timepoint, state , parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    dX = a * X
    list(c(dX))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a more complete example, using the function `test`of the original poster:

```r
library("deSolve")
test <- function(timepoint, state , parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    dX <- a * X
    list(c(dX))
  })
}

test2  <- function(timepoint, state , parameters) {
    dX <- parameters["a"] * state["X"]
    list(dX)
}

state0 <- c(X = 1)
pars   <- c(a = 0.5)
times  <- seq(0, 10, 0.1)

out <- ode(state0, times, test, pars)

out2 <- ode(state0, times, test2, pars)

plot(out, out2)
```

Here, functions `test` and `test2` do exactly the same, but the equation is easier to read in version `test`. The `with(as.list(...))`-construction just unpacks the contents of state and parameters, so that the differential equation(s) can be written less technically, i.e. similar to mathematical notation. The benefit is more obvious in bigger models with more than one equation.

The return value of `test` is a list with two elements, as defined in the **deSolve** documentation. The help page of `ode` tells us:

> The return value of `func` should be a list, whose first element is a vector containing the derivatives of `y` with respect to time, and whose next elements are global values that are required at each point in times. The derivatives must be specified in the same order as the state variables `y`.

This means that it may contain one or more elements, where the first is a vector of the derivatives and the other are optional other internal values of the ODE model that are to be stored. In the example here `list(dX)` would be enough. The `list(c(dX))` notation ist often used for didactical reasons to indicate that the first element of the list (the vector) may contain more elements, precisely as many as the number of states given in the initial state `state0`. It can for example be: `list(c(dX, dY, dZ))`, given that a model has **three states**. Or it may be `list(c(dX, dY, dZ), a, b, c)` if we want to save **internal** or "global" variables from the model.

The plot at the end is just to show that `test`and `test2` give the same results.

Comment: where do you use these `a`, `b` and `c` then? Where are they stored?

Comment: `a`, `b`, `c` are just examples for any variables that are not state variables but are used in the model function and the user wants that the solver returns it.

Comment: to answer my own comment.. they end up in the ouput, but they are not useable in the `func`-part.

Comment: Yes, they are in the output but of course not part of the input. Why should they? If you have a question about this, then please post a new question with reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

`as.list` transforms named vectors to a list, for example :

```r
state = c(X = 1)
parameters = c(a = 3, b = 4)

# Create a named vector
c(state,parameters)
#> X a b 
#> 1 3 4

# Convert to list
as.list(c(state, parameters))
#> $X
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 4
```

`with` evaluates the RHS expression inside LHS environment.

In the example below it makes `a`, `b` and `X` available for evaluation:

```r
with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {dX = a*X; dX})
[1] 6
```

To answer the third part of your question, providing examples of `state` and `parameters` would be useful.